# Ruby gem for resolving pluralization in English

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

This is strange question in sense that I don't think there is answer for it but here it goes.

I am looking for `gem` which would allow me to get root word from pluralized word.

```
categories => category
people     => person
apples     => apple
```

Trick is I need it in ruby and not in ROR so solution should be independent from `ActiveRecord` which probably has this mechanism built in. Thanks. There is also paper on this subject that I found http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~damian/papers/HTML/Plurals.html/ in case somebody is interested in building the gem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour is defined in [ActiveSupport](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb#L54), which you can include on its own without having to require Rails completely.

```
>> require 'rubygems'
=> true
>> require 'active_support/core_ext/string/inflections'
=> true
>> "categories".singularize
=> "category"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can require just the inflections from `ActiveSupport`, leaving out the rest of rails, like this:

`require 'active_support/core_ext/string/inflections'`

If that doesn't work for you, check out the [inflections](https://github.com/davidcelis/inflections) gem.

Answer (score 0):

You could always install just the active_support gem, and require just the inflector, that way you don't load all of rails.   Many parts of rails can be used independently.

```
$ irb
1.9.3-p194 :001 > require 'active_support/inflector'
=> true 
1.9.3-p194 :002 > ActiveSupport::Inflector.singularize('inflections')
=> "inflection"
```